# Only vertically sticky HTML div

Tags: html, css

is it possible to make a div vertically sticky but not sticky horizontally?
cheers
Ali

Comment: What would cause it to move horizontally? Just the initial layout, or do you expect elements to push it back and forth as the page layout changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only chance you have of doing this in pure CSS involves the `position: fixed` property, but this requires offsets which are constant, based upon the window.

You can do it quite simply by using a bit of jQuery if you are familiar with the JavasSript library:

```
$(window).bind('scroll resize', function() {
    $('#the-sticky-div').css('top', $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

This requires a bit of CSS also to enable it to work:

```
#the-sticky-div {
    position: relative;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/SYqXJ/23/

Comment: just a quick (dumb) question: in the demo, it is done for div, how can do it for the an element id?

Comment: Is there a way to handle the flicker you see in Firefox (3.6.17)?  Chrome and IE seem to be fine.

Comment: I am seeing flickering in both Chrome (11) and Firefox (4.0.1), I cannot remember if didn't do that before but I cannot think of a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I can't understand the contradicting statements, so I'll answer the first one ;)

`position: fixed` is your friend in this case, but I'm not sure how it can and can't be vertically sticky at the same time...

Comment: thanks for trying... but please see Marcus Whybrow's demo in the accepted answer to understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

i think that if you position the element absolute and then only set its top to zero, it should only stick to the top.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<div style="position:fixed; background:yellow;">
 <h1>S<BR>T<BR>A<BR>C<BR>K<BR><BR>O<BR>V<BR>E<BR>R<BR>F<BR>L<BR>O<BR>W</h1>
</div>

<div style="white-space: nowrap;">
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt 
</div>
```